# setting up vhosts.conf for multiple domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up httpd-vhosts.conf for multiple virtual hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/220951/setting-up-httpd-vhosts-conf-for-multiple-virtual-hosts)

Say I have dedicated ip 155.5.5.5
I have all of the dns setup properly for two domains
www.a.com and www.b.com

In my apache directory I have
/var/www/a/
/var/www/b/

How do I setup the apache vhosts.conf file so that 
The ip (155.5.5.5) goes to /var/www/,
A.com goes to /var/www/a,
B.com goes to /var/www/b
?

Comment: gonna have to flag this questiona as it's been answered many times on SF already mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Name based virtual hosts

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName a.com
ServerAlias www.a.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName b.com
ServerName www.b.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/b
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html

Depending on your distro the virtual hosts go in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ or just the bottom of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

The [slicehost articles](http://articles.slicehost.com) are great for starting out with linux sysadmin/apache/etc.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Was wondering how I might get the ip to go to the root directory?